# Learning about defining functions in my Python class and confused about the output of my code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Problem: Write a Python function, square, that takes in one number and returns the square of that number.

This function takes in one number and returns one number.

Code given:

```
def square(x):
    '''
    x: int or float.
    '''
```

My code:

```
def square(x):
    '''
    x: int or float.
    '''
    x = x * x
    print x
```

Output:

```
Test: square(-5.0)
Your output:
25.0
None

Correct output:
25.0


Test: square(3.17)
Your output:
10.0489
None

Correct output:
10.0489

Test: square(-3.4)
Your output:
11.56
None

Correct output:
11.559999999999999
```

Why is my code printing out (a) "None", and in some cases (b) the incorrect answer?

Comment: For completeness, the results you see are correct. The difference between your output and the expected output in the last case is likely due to different output methods. Many Python versions print fewer significant digits when using `str(some_float)`, including when using `print`, than when using `repr(some_float)` which the "correct output" appears to use. Very recent Python versions use the same algorithm for both (which often produces shorter output than the old algorithm of `repr`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't return any value from your function, it will return `None` by default.

So, if you try to print the return value of your function, you will get `None`. So, simply don't print the result of the function call.

You can change your function to return the computed *square* rather than printing it:

```
def square(x):
    '''
    x: int or float.
    '''
    return x * x
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it was as simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `None` because you're calling your function like this:

```
print square(3.17)
```

In other words, you are printing the return value of the function. But the function does not return anything; in other words, it returns `None`.

There is no reason to call the function that way since it *already* prints the result. Simply call it like this:

```
square(3.17)
```

Or change the function so it returns the result instead of printing it.  (Which is probably the better approach, since it makes the function more generally useful -- sometimes you might not want to print the result, after all.)

As to the incorrect answers, binary floating point math cannot represent all fractional numbers perfectly. Numbers that look finite in decimal may have infinite binary representations; for example, `3.4` is one such. Therefore all finite representations are by definition approximations and mathematical operations will often give results that are slightly "off." Python tries to hide these discrepancies when printing your numbers, but it cannot always do this. A solution is to use the `Decimal` class (in the `decimal` module) to represent your numbers.